# Add class on visible elements

Tags: jquery, addclass

I want to add a new `class` 'visible-offers' on all of my visible elements.
I am retrieving the visible ones by the following line of code:

```
$('.pan-box').filter(':visible')
```

It returns all those `visible` divs with class 'pan-box'. Now how can I add the new class to these returned divs

Comment: Use .addClass('your-class');

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: and you don't need to use `filter()` just use `:visible` https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/  on your selector ... this is just basic and easy to find with google

Comment: `$('.pan-box:visible').addClass('class');`

Comment: `$('.pan-box:visible').addClass('newclass');`

Comment: @DaniP jQuery's documentation states: *"Because :visible is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :visible cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :visible to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":visible")."*

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=add%20class%20jquery

Comment: @billyonecan good point thanks for the clarification ... Aside I refer to basic and easy to find how to add a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.pan-box').filter(':visible').addClass('visible-offers');`

Documentation about [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: You can use `$('.pan-box':visible')` instead `filter()`

Comment: @Mohammad yeap, but this way is more flexible I think

Answer (score 0):

By using **[.addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** method. you can also narrow down selector to target visible element:

```
$('.pan-box:visible').addClass('visible-offers');
```

Answer (score 0):

add `addClass` to your code, `$('.pan-box').filter(':visible').addClass('visible-offers')`